# Activate input text box onchange select box

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

Having trouble making this work. I want a textbox input First_name2 to appear only when "Household" is selected in the select box. No matter where I put the jquery code, it doesn't work. Is this because the form is embedded in 2 tables?

jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLqxj/

```
$('#membership').change(function () {
    $('#first_name2').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'Household') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I uncommented the HTML around the #first_name2 element in your fiddle, and it seems that the jQuery is working as you expected (show #first_name2 when Household is selected, hide when Household is unselected). This is on Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m.

Comment: In your fiddle, the `#first_name2` element is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$('#membership').change(function () {
    if ($('#membership :selected').attr("value")=="Household") {
        $("#first_name2row").show();
    } else {
        $("#first_name2row").hide();
    }
});
```

I introduced a new ID for the `<TR>` that holds the spouse first name because that's what you want to hide. Alternatively, to avoid the new ID you could also use this but readability is lower:

```
$("#first_name2").parent().parent().show()
```

and

```
$("#first_name2").parent().parent().hide()
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricis/fpqUz/)

Comment: I didn't mean to leave the row commented out. It's working in the jsfiddle but not on my page. Where do you have the script code so that it will work? Is there a scope issue when using tables? Thanks!

Comment: In principle it shouldn't be a problem to have the form spread across tables. But if it works in the fiddle, either with your code or mine (see my fiddle forked from yours), then it should work in your page unless there are bigger issues. What is the console saying?

Comment: $ not defined       $('#membership').change(function () {

Comment: I trust you are including the jQuery library: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and that you have encapsulated the jQuery code like this: `<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function(){` **your code goes here** `}</script>`

Comment: I think that's the problem. I had originally used javascript code to try to get it working but then switched to jquery but forgot about linking it to the library. I bet it will work if i do that.

Comment: Still not working. No error in console. I'll post a new fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/LmpaM/      I have the jquery link in the head and the jquery code before the ending body tag.

Comment: I had a error in the console... `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` then I activated jQuery on the left side **Frameworks and Extensions** and it worked immediately... :-) **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmpaM/1/)**

Comment: Great news then! Glad to be of help!